# How to only allow certain countries access to your website?

Tags: html

A couple days ago we were flooded with emails from countries like Russia, Ukraine, etc and we don't ship to anywhere except Canada and the United States so 
I was wondering if instead of blocking multiple countries, I could only set my website to access from Canada or United States somehow in the html?

I was looking at the referrals from those countries and they were from websites like "http://ilovefreebies.ru" .... why is my website even coming up on these sites in Russia? Is it possible to remove them?

TIA.

Comment: Your title is asking about a website but your question body is asking about email. Which is it?

Comment: I have a contact form on my website that can be filled out and then we get an email with their request. But people had to come to my website somehow to find the form. So when we were getting hundreds of emails from that contact form sent to us via email these people from those countries had to have found my website somehow. @Quentin

Comment: Why is my website even coming up on these sites in Russia" — It isn't. Referers lie.

Comment: @Quentin actually it is, the website that it is on is www.ilovefreebies.ru
the top ad on this site is my website.